# Bootstrap 5 modal shows only the first modal in a list of modals

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5 and Jinja for loop to have a list of Bootstrap modals together. Only the first modal shows, the others don't show. what could be the issue and how can I fix this, please?

Code below:

```
{% for course in all_courses %}
<!--Register modal -->
<div class="modal" id="register_modal_{{course.id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Register Course: {{course.course_title}}</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        <div>
        <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('home_blueprints.register_course') }}">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!--hidden input for the course id -->
                <input type="hidden" name="course_id" value="{{course.id}}">
                <!--username-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">Enter Username</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        id="username"
                        name="username"
                        placeholder="Enter username"
                    />
                </div>
                
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register Now</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--End Register modal -->
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing with the Bootstrap modals not showing except for the first one is likely due to the incorrect placement of the closing  tag in your modal structure.

In your code snippet, the  tag following the  element is misplaced. It should come after the closing  tag of the modal dialog, but it seems to be placed before the form element.

To fix this, simply move the misplaced  tag to the correct position, as shown below:

```html
{% for course in all_courses %}
<!-- Register modal -->
<div class="modal" id="register_modal_{{course.id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Register Course: {{course.course_title}}</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('home_blueprints.register_course') }}">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <!-- hidden input for the course id -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="course_id" value="{{course.id}}">
                    <!-- username -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username">Enter Username</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            class="form-control"
                            id="username"
                            name="username"
                            placeholder="Enter username"
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register Now</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End Register modal -->
{% endfor %}
```

By moving the closing  tag to its correct position, each modal will have the proper structure and be displayed correctly when triggered.